# Model/View-like editing in Emacs

Tags: json, model-view-controller, emacs, elisp

I have some JSON files and I'm writing a mode that allows editing a single property of the JSON object independently from the rest. For example:

foo.json:

```
{
  "creation_timestamp": "1411210038.000000",
  "description": "lorem ipsum.\ndolor sit amet.",
  "version": 4
}
```

Opening foo.json results in this buffer:

```
lorem ipsum.

dolor sit amet.
```

Changing the first line to "foo bar" and saving the file results in a `foo.json` with only the `description` field updated:

```
{
  "creation_timestamp": "1411210038.000000",
  "description": "foo bar.\ndolor sit amet.",
  "version": 4
}
```

What's the best strategy for this? My current attempt is so:

1. open the JSON file with find-file
2. create an invisible overlay from point-min to point-max
3. parse json
4. insert the value of the `description` property at point-min, creating a "view"
5. add a local-write-file hook and an after-save hook

The `local-write-file` hook kills the "view", updates the json in the overlay, and saves the file. The `after-save` hook recreates the "view" so the user can keep editing.

This is long-winded and brittle. Is there a better way of working with data where the screen representation should be different than the disk representation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your own encoding and decoding in `format-alist` for that purpose.
Your example could be implemented in the following way:

```lisp
(defvar-local my-head nil
  "Header of json file cut off by json-descr format.")

(defvar-local my-tail nil
  "Tail of json file cut off by json-descr format.")

(defun my-from-fn (BEGIN END)
  "`format-alist'"
  (save-restriction
    (narrow-to-region BEGIN END)
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (let* ((b (re-search-forward "^[[:blank:]]*\"description\":[[:blank:]]*\"" nil t))
       (e (ignore-errors (1- (scan-sexps (1- b) 1)))))
      (unless (and b e)
    (error "Error in original mode")) ;;< TODO some more sensible error message
      ;; Save head and tail and delete corresponding buffer regions:
      (setq-local my-head (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) b))
      (setq-local my-tail (buffer-substring-no-properties e (point-max)))
      (delete-region e (point-max))
      (delete-region (point-min) b)
      ;; Formatting:
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (search-forward "\\n" nil t)
    (replace-match "\n"))
      )
    (point-max) ;;< required by `format-alist'
    ))

(defun my-to-fn (BEGIN END BUFFER)
  "`format-alist'"
  (save-restriction
    (narrow-to-region BEGIN END)
    ;; Formatting:
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (search-forward "\n" nil t)
      (replace-match "\\\\n"))
    ;; Insert head and tail:
    (let ((head (with-current-buffer BUFFER my-head))
      (tail (with-current-buffer BUFFER my-tail)))
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (insert head)
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (insert tail))
    (point-max)))

(add-to-list 'format-alist
         '(json-descr
           "File format for editing a single property of a json object."
           nil
           my-from-fn
           my-to-fn
           t ; MODIFY: my-to-fn modifies the buffer
           nil
           nil))

(define-derived-mode my-mode fundamental-mode "JDescr"
  "Major mode for editing json description properties."
  (format-decode-buffer 'json-descr))
```

---

Actually, one can also interpret this as a more general problem. Load a file into a hidden buffer. Use another visible buffer to edit its transformed content. At saving the visible buffer actually transform the content back to the original format and save the hidden buffer.

I do not have the time right now to implement the general case as described above.
The following code roughly covers your special case. (Note, that it is a fast hack for demonstration purposes only.)

```lisp
(defvar-local original-mode-other nil
  "Other buffer related to the current one.")


(define-derived-mode original-mode special-mode ""
  "Opens file in invisible auxiliary buffer."
  (let* ((b (re-search-forward "^[[:blank:]]*\"description\":[[:blank:]]*\"" nil t))
     (e (ignore-errors (1- (scan-sexps (1- b) 1))))
     (original-name (buffer-name))
     (original-buffer (current-buffer))
     str)
    (unless (and b e)
      (error "Error in original mode")) ;; TODO some more sensible error message
    (narrow-to-region b e)
    (setq str (buffer-substring-no-properties b e))
    (rename-buffer (concat " *" original-name))
    (with-current-buffer (switch-to-buffer (get-buffer-create original-name))
      ;; Set-up the clone buffer for editing the transformed content:
      (set-visited-file-name (buffer-file-name original-buffer) t)
      (setq original-mode-other original-buffer)
      (insert str)
      (set-buffer-modified-p nil)
      ;; Transform content to the format of the clone buffer:
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (search-forward "\\n" nil t) ;; TODO: Skip escaped \n.
    (replace-match "\n"))
      (add-to-list 'write-contents-functions  (lambda ()
                        ;; Transfer content to original buffer
                        (let ((str (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max))))
                          (with-current-buffer original-mode-other
                            (let ((inhibit-read-only t))
                              (delete-region (point-min) (point-max))
                              (insert str)
                              (goto-char (point-min))
                              ;; Transform content to the format of the original buffer:
                              (while (search-forward "\n" nil t)
                            (replace-match "\\\\n"))
                              (save-buffer)
                              )))
                        (set-buffer-modified-p nil)
                        t))
      (add-hook 'kill-buffer-hook (lambda ()
                    (kill-buffer original-mode-other)) t t)
      )))
```

Comment: @hyperstruct I removed the note of `jka-compr` for two reasons: 1. `jka-compr` uses mainly external programs; 2. it hooks too deeply into internal emacs functions.

Comment: May want to prefer json.el over re-search-forward (see http://edward.oconnor.cx/2006/03/json.el) It's included since emacs 23.1.

Comment: @hyperstruct I think the most natural way is to use `format-alist`. I included a solution to your example at the beginning of the answer. The bookkeeping of the auxiliary buffers is done by the `format`-package.

Comment: Beautiful. I wasn't familiar with Emacs format handling; after re-implementing my mode this way, I think it's the best match for the problem.

A note to future readers: in `my-to-fn`, the `with-current-buffer` calls are crucial. Initially I left them out, thinking that `my-to-fn` would have access to the buffer-local `my-head` and `my-tail` variable anyway; not so. I haven't looked into it further but I assume that `my-to-fn` runs into a temporary auxiliary buffer created by the format conversion process.

@Tobias regarding the multiple-buffer idea, see my comment to Drew's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is your use case really as simple as the scenario you describe (not the solution outline, but the problem/use case)?

If so, your solution sounds like overkill. If the use case is as simple as editing the value of a particular key, I would probably do this:

1. Display the content of that field (value corresponding to the key) in a temporary buffer, for editing.
2. Bind a key (e.g., `C-c C-c`) to save the edited value back to the file.

I do that in [**Bookmark+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/BookmarkPlus) for editing a bookmark's tags, for instance (and also for editing all of a bookmark's fields, using a different command). The command to edit the tags is `bmkp-edit-tags`. The command (bound to `C-c C-c` in the edit buffer) is `bmkp-edit-tags-send`.  The code is [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/bookmark%2b-1.el), in context.  Here it is, out of context:

---

```
(defmacro bmkp-with-output-to-plain-temp-buffer (buf &rest body)
  "Like `with-output-to-temp-buffer', but with no `*Help*' navigation stuff."
  `(unwind-protect
    (progn
      (remove-hook 'temp-buffer-setup-hook 'help-mode-setup)
      (remove-hook 'temp-buffer-show-hook  'help-mode-finish)
      (with-output-to-temp-buffer ,buf ,@body))
    (add-hook 'temp-buffer-setup-hook 'help-mode-setup)
    (add-hook 'temp-buffer-show-hook  'help-mode-finish)))

(define-derived-mode bmkp-edit-tags-mode emacs-lisp-mode
    "Edit Bookmark Tags"
  "Mode for editing bookmark tags.
When you have finished composing, type \\[bmkp-edit-tags-send]."
  :group 'bookmark-plus)

;; This binding must be defined *after* the mode, so `bmkp-edit-tags-mode-map' is defined.
;; (Alternatively, we could use a `defvar' to define `bmkp-edit-tags-mode-map' before
;; calling `define-derived-mode'.)
(define-key bmkp-edit-tags-mode-map "\C-c\C-c" 'bmkp-edit-tags-send)

(defun bmkp-edit-tags (bookmark)        ; Bound to `C-x p t e'
  "Edit BOOKMARK's tags, and maybe save the result.
The edited value must be a list each of whose elements is either a
 string or a cons whose key is a string.
BOOKMARK is a bookmark name or a bookmark record."
  (interactive (list (bookmark-completing-read "Edit tags for bookmark" (bmkp-default-bookmark-name))))
  (setq bookmark  (bmkp-get-bookmark-in-alist bookmark))
  (let* ((btags    (bmkp-get-tags bookmark))
         (bmkname  (bmkp-bookmark-name-from-record bookmark))
         (edbuf    (format "*Edit Tags for Bookmark `%s'*" bmkname)))
    (setq bmkp-return-buffer  (current-buffer))
    (bmkp-with-output-to-plain-temp-buffer edbuf
      (princ
       (substitute-command-keys
        (concat ";; Edit tags for bookmark\n;;\n;; \"" bmkname "\"\n;;\n"
                ";; The edited value must be a list each of whose elements is\n"
                ";; either a string or a cons whose key is a string.\n;;\n"
                ";; DO NOT MODIFY THESE COMMENTS.\n;;\n"
                ";; Type \\<bmkp-edit-tags-mode-map>`\\[bmkp-edit-tags-send]' when done.\n\n")))
      (let ((print-circle  bmkp-propertize-bookmark-names-flag)) (pp btags))
      (goto-char (point-min)))
    (pop-to-buffer edbuf)
    (buffer-enable-undo)
    (with-current-buffer (get-buffer edbuf) (bmkp-edit-tags-mode))))

(defun bmkp-edit-tags-send (&optional batchp)
  "Use buffer contents as the internal form of a bookmark's tags.
DO NOT MODIFY the header comment lines, which begin with `;;'."
  (interactive)
  (unless (eq major-mode 'bmkp-edit-tags-mode) (error "Not in `bmkp-edit-tags-mode'"))
  (let (bname)
    (unwind-protect
         (let (tags bmk)
           (goto-char (point-min))
           (unless (search-forward ";; Edit tags for bookmark\n;;\n;; ")
             (error "Missing header in edit buffer"))
           (unless (stringp (setq bname  (read (current-buffer))))
             (error "Bad bookmark name in edit-buffer header"))
           (unless (setq bmk  (bmkp-get-bookmark-in-alist bname 'NOERROR))
             (error "No such bookmark: `%s'" bname))
           (unless (bmkp-bookmark-type bmk) (error "Invalid bookmark"))
           (goto-char (point-min))
           (setq tags  (read (current-buffer)))
           (unless (listp tags) (error "Tags sexp is not a list of strings or an alist with string keys"))
           (bookmark-prop-set bmk 'tags tags)
           (setq bname  (bmkp-bookmark-name-from-record bmk))
           (bmkp-record-visit bmk batchp)
           (bmkp-refresh/rebuild-menu-list bname batchp)
           (bmkp-maybe-save-bookmarks)
           (unless batchp (message "Updated bookmark file with edited tags")))
      (kill-buffer (current-buffer)))
    (when bmkp-return-buffer
      (pop-to-buffer bmkp-return-buffer)
      (when (equal (buffer-name (current-buffer)) "*Bookmark List*")
        (bmkp-bmenu-goto-bookmark-named bname)))))
```

---

The most relevant bits are these:

1. Define a command to initiate editing and a command to end it and save the changes.
2. Provide an edit buffer using `bmkp-with-output-to-plain-temp-buffer` (essentially `with-output-to-temp-buffer`, but that macro in some Emacs versions also adds *Help* mode stuff not needed here).
3. Put the edit buffer in a simple minor mode that binds `C-c C-c` to the save-and-exit command.
4. Fill the edit buffer with the text to be edited.  Pop to the buffer, for editing.
5. In the save-and-exit command (`bmkp-edit-tags-send`), update the original data, replacing the relevant field contents with the edit-buffer contents.  Save the updated data.  Return to the original buffer.

Comment: This is interesting and taught me a good deal, however I think it deals with a slightly different problem. If I understand correctly, in Bookmark+ the "model" buffer (the bookmark list) is still meant for user consumption; it will be created before "edit" buffers and will outlive them. In my case, the "model" buffer should be invisible during opening, frozen during editing, and destroyed after saving. All attainable with ad hoc book-keeping, or almost (I don't think it's possible to prevent killing a buffer), I prefer to avoid that if possible though. :)