# Preprocess/postprocess a file upon visiting and writing it in emacs

Tags: xml, json, emacs, elisp

I have a bunch of rather verbose xml files that are named in a certain way like "verbosefile_*.xml". I have a pair of python scripts that transform these xml files into a compact json format and vice versa. Currently my workflow is that I first convert the verbose xml file into a compact json file using my script, make changes or edits to that file, and then convert the compact json version back to the verbose xml format. I wanted this process to happen transparently whenever I visit/open a file in emacs. Basically, my new workflow should be that upon opening the verbose xml files directly from the editor, I should see the compact json representation, and upon writing the file, the json should be converted behind the scenes to the verbose xml format and written. Some hints on how to do this would be great. I am new to elisp and the emacs hooks/functions, even if I have been using the editor for some time.

EDIT: I can change the python scripts to make things easier. For example, if the scripts working on std input makes the problem easier to solve, I can do that.

Comment: Here is a link to the documentation regarding setting up a sentinel:  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sentinels.html  Here is a link to the documentation regarding setting up a filter for the process (just in case you need to monitor the process output and take certain action based on said output):  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Filter-Functions.html  Here is a link to the documentation discussing using `start-process`:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Asynchronous-Processes.html#Asynchronous-Processes

Comment: Once you get that process stuff out of the way, the rest will be a piece of cake -- using either a major-mode hook or a find-file-hook or something like those.  I'd start first with the process stuff -- get that working, and then a simple Google for emacs add-hook and whatever major mode you are using should get you what you need.

Comment: Take a look at `hexl-mode`. This is a hex editor that use an external command to dump a file to a human-readable format and, upon saving, convert it back again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various ways to do what you ask.

One of them, that was meant to be "the canonical way" (although it seems it is not used very often) is to use `format-alist`.  In your case, the detection of the format is based on the file-name rather than the file-contents, so you'd globally add an entry to `format-alist` where the REGEXP part is nil.  Then you'd setup a special mode via `auto-mode-alist` and that mode would start by passing the buffer's contents through your first script (with `call-process-region`), then set `buffer-file-format` to indicate that you're using the format you've added to `format-alist`.

Another option is to use a `file-name-handler-alist`, as we do for .gz files.

Yet another option is to use a special mode (as above) but instead of setting up `format-alist` and `buffer-file-format`, you'd simply `(add-hook 'write-file-functions #'my-write-hook nil t)` and make `my-write-hook` save the file using the second script.

Answer (score 1):

I have a different on-disc format (gjots) and I wanted to edit them using emacs' org-mode.

Since format-alist can't use a file extension like *.gjots, I followed the previous post's description of the technique and (coupled with the code at [Model/View-like editing in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26488808/model-view-like-editing-in-emacs/26501118#26501118)) I got to this working solution to the original problem:

```
(setq format-alist
      (cons '(gjots "gjots" nil "gjots2org" "org2gjots" t nil) format-alist))
(define-derived-mode gjots-mode org-mode "gjots"
  "Major mode for editing gjots files."
  (format-decode-buffer 'gjots))
(autoload 'gjots-mode "gjots-mode" "Major mode to edit gjots files." t)
(setq auto-mode-alist
      (cons '("\\.gjots$" . gjots-mode) auto-mode-alist))
```